# CSS animation not following rules specified in the keyframes?

Tags: css

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/joshuajazleung/pen/ayNwWv)

```
<div></div>

html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  background: black;
  transform: translate(100px, 50px) rotate(140deg);
  animation: circle-top 1.5s ease-in-out forwards;
}

@keyframes circle-top {
  10% {
    transform: translate(500, -190px) rotate(120deg);
  }
  30% {
    transform: translate(300, -150px) rotate(100deg);
  }
  70% {
    transform: translate(100, -50px) rotate(360deg);
  }
  90% {
    transform: translate(50, -30px) rotate(30deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(0, 0) rotate(0);
  }
}
```

I specified some random rotation in the keyframes. Obviously the animation is not following the rules because it seems to be so smooth and not how I specified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@keyframes circle-top {
  10% {
    transform: translate(500, -190px) rotate(120deg);
                      /* !!! */ 
  }
```

Your *invalid* value for the first translate parameter is causing most of your keyframes to become invalid as well.

Every length in CSS always needs a unit, unless the value happens to be 0.